# How to switch defined appenders in logback

Tags: logback

I have a defined logback in my project, and here is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="DAILY" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/logApp/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/logApp/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="HOURLY" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/logApp/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/logApp/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="DAILY" />
</root>
```

A you can see I only use daily appender in my root configuration. How can I switch between those defined appenders (HOURLY / DAILY) in runtime?

I have tried with the following code, but my newAppender is always null:

```
String loggingAppender = "HOURLY";
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = lc.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.detachAndStopAllAppenders();
Appender<ILoggingEvent> newAppender = root.getAppender(loggingAppender);
root.addAppender(newAppender);
```

Comment: One option is to simply implement your own Logback logger, then you can do anything since it's plain Java / Kotlin code.

```class Logging : AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>() {```